# Apache 2.4 ErrorDocument 401 breaks basic authentification

Tags: linux, apache-2.4

I got an issue with the basic authentication, when I add ErrorDocument 401 /var/www/rainbow/static/401.html you can click on cancel on auth prompt and you got access without auth .

Here is my site conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Protocols h2 http/1.1
    ServerName XXX.app
    ServerAlias XXX.app

    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|svg)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    </FilesMatch>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/rainbow/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/rainbow-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/rainbow-access.log combined

    ErrorDocument 401 /var/www/html/static/401.html

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXXX
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXXXX
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

    
</VirtualHost>
```